# Pivot to transpose row to column in Spark structured streaming using scala

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

We are using **Spark** structured streaming 2.4.1 version to process events from Kafka to Cassandra. The event is a nested JSON and we need to flatten the data and load in Cassandra table.

I tried to use pivot on dataframe but it is throwing below error message. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

### Json event structure -

```
{
  "event_name": "some event",
  "groups": [
    {
      "data_group_name": "personname",
      "fields": [
        {
          "col_name": "firstname",
          "value": "John"
        },
        {
          "col_name": "lastname",
          "value": "williams"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data_group_name": "contact",
      "fields": [
        {
          "col_name": "mobile",
          "value": "1234567890"
        },
        {
          "col_name": "home",
          "value": "0987654321"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

df.pivot($"col_name").agg(first($"value"),null)
```

Expected Result:

```
----------------
event_name  firstname   lastname    mobile          home
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
some event  John            williams    1234567890  987654321
```

Error Message -

> Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
>   writeStream.start();; kafka
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:389)

Comment: Have you solved that?

Comment: Using spark 2.4.4, same problem here :/